# How to change the font for a specific store view in magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, fonts

I have two store-views which are English and Arabic and would like to change the font of the Arabic store-view for all front-end contents. please any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two themes for English which is using (left to right) and Arabic (right to left). So you can add two different fonts for two themes and change the theme for a specific store view. Hope this will help you.